# How to store the output of "call"?...Batch Code

Tags: batch-file

I'm using Windows XP.

My batch (file) code has a line like this:

```
 call echo %%x[%i%]%%
```

I want to store the output of this line into a variable and I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do it.

Comment: have you done any kind of research in this question The [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/) site should be a good starting point. In this case especially the [set-command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store it into a variable, why do you echo it?

This should do the job

```
call set myVar=%%x[%i%]%%
```

Comment: and why do you need to `CALL` it? just `SET myvar`.

Comment: @PA - You need the call to do a double expansion, first the %i% and then the `%x<i>%`, probably to access a pseudo array

Comment: oh, I see, I didnt pay attention to the right side of the assignment :(